# How can I convert a string, such as "iso-8859-1", to it's String.Encoding counterpart?

Tags: swift, string, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

After sending a HTTP request from Swift, I get a field in the response called `textEncodingName`.

I want to convert the `data` object I also received into a string containing its contents, and to do this, I'm using `String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)`. This works most of the time, because most websites are UTF-8 encoded. But with, for example, `https://www.google.co.uk`, the `response.textEncodingName == "iso-8859-1"`.

I guess other websites would use even more obscure encodings, so my question is this: how can I find the right encoding to convert my `data` object to the correct string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply try `String.Encoding.windowsCP1250` for `iso-8859-1`. Please refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250

```
String(data: data, encoding: .windowsCP1250)
```

OR..

I found a few steps that will take you from the `textEncodingName` to the corresponding `String.Encoding` value:

```
let estr = "iso-8859-1"
let cfe = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding(estr as CFString)
let se = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(cfe)
let encoding = String.Encoding(rawValue: se)
```

This is largely based on the documentation for `URLResponse.textEncodingName`:

> You can convert this string to a CFStringEncoding value by calling CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding(*:). You can subsequently convert that value to an NSStringEncoding value by calling CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(*:).

Here's an update that checks to see if the original text encoding string is valid or not:

```
let estr = "XXX"
let cfe = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding(estr as CFString)
if cfe != kCFStringEncodingInvalidId {
    let se = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(cfe)
    let sse = String.Encoding(rawValue: se)
    print("sse = \(sse)")
} else {
    print("Invalid")
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea what would happen if the encoding wasn't recognized?

Comment: @Zac See my update to check if the encoding is valid or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would write an enum with a `String` raw value and a computed property to return the appropriate `String.Encoding` value. Then you can use its `init(rawValue:)` to create an instance.

```
import Foundation

enum APITextEncoding : String
{
    case iso8859_1 = "iso-8859-1"
    // etc.

    var encoding: String.Encoding
    {
        switch self
        {
            case .iso8859_1:
                return .isoLatin1
            // etc.
        }
    }
}

let receivedEncoding = APITextEncoding(rawValue: encodingDescription)
let receivedText = String(data: receivedData, encoding: receivedEncoding.encoding)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift You can use:

```
guard let string =  String(data: data, encoding: .isoLatin1) else {return}

guard let perfectData = string.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: true) else {return}
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift you can use:

```
func getTextFrom(_ url: URL) -> String?  {
    guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
        return nil
    }
    return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ??
        String(data: data, encoding: .isoLatin1)
}
```